# Using Iteration to solve for independent and dependent variables at once

Tags: r, forecasting

In an [older piece by Nate Silver](http://www.espn.com/world-cup/story/_/id/4447078/ce/us/guide-espn-spi-ratings) -- explaining the methodology of ESPN's Soccer Power Index (SPI) -- he explains how he calculates team ratings. However, he notes that in doing so he uses loops to solve for the independent and dependent variables at once. Here is a portion of his explanation:

> Fortunately, there is a shortcut -- a process known as iteration. This is the same process used for many of the more popular college football and college basketball rankings. We start with an initial estimate of opponent quality -- for example, how many goals the opponent scored and allowed over all games in the database. Then this estimate is continually refined -- made more and more accurate -- each time we run through another iteration or "loop" and incorporate more information. After about 20 to 30 iterations, this estimate becomes stable down to several decimal places, and we are able to calculate reliable OFF and DEF factors for any given team on any given date.

I am curious as to the nature of how this iteration works from both a theoretical understanding as well as how to apply it. Possible R code would be useful as well. I appreciate any guidance on understanding this technique.

Comment: The ESPN piece explaining there Soccer Power Index has been removed from their site. Was Nate Silver's piece a question on CV?  If so can you provide a link to us. I think it would be helpful to see the comments and answers on that post.

Comment: It is linked in the first sentence! Hope that helps @MichaelChernick